# How can I create conductor's annotations in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I'm writing a second edition of a *Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time* medley I wrote and conducted in high school (it was indeed as fun as it sounds).  Through our rehearsals, my director and I penciled in a bunch of changes that I somehow never got around to putting into the source code.  Unfortunately, I lost all that code—it was before I'd begun my computer science studies and discovered `git` and `make`.  However, this gives me the opportunity to do things over the right way.

My project structure is the same as the example given in [section 5.5 of the Lilypond Usage manual](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/usage/make-and-makefiles).  While some of the edits we made were applicable to the parts—articulations added or removed, *etc.*—some of them are meant purely for the conductor, such as reminders to cue sections of the orchestra.  What's the best way to insert these?  As far as I can tell, the `.ly` file containing the full score is nothing more than a series of `\include` directives, but that denies me the ability to add further information to a staff once it's included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess a good, pure-Lilypond way would be using tags ([see docs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/different-editions-from-one-source#using-tags)).

In short: you can annotate anything in your score with `\tag #'whatever`. An example could be

```
flutes = { \global
  \tag #'fullscore { c4-\markup\italic "wave hands at the flutes!" }
    \tag #'parts { c4 } d e f |
  g4 a b c' |
}
```

Then, you can use `\keepWithTag` or `\removeWithTag`. So, in the conductor's score, you would replace `\new Staff \with { instrumentName = "Flutes" } { \flutes }` with `\new Staff \with { instrumentName = "Flutes" } { \keepWithTag #'fullscore \flutes }`. That will keep only things tagged with `#'fullscore` and with nothing, and discard everything else, so you will get the "wave hands at the flutes!" markup.

Similarly you would use `\removeWithTag #'fullscore` (or `\keepWithTag #'parts`) in the parts to get rid of the markup.

Comment: Just tried this, and it works perfectly.  Thanks!